# Skip keychain without skipping the rest of .profile

Tags: bash, shell, keychain

I am using the `keychain` ssh-agent wrapper from funtoo.org.

I have it loaded automatically by adding an `eval` line in my `.profile`. E.g.:

```
eval `keychain --eval id_rsa github bitbucket`
```

Sometimes, I log into the login shell for the first time (e.g. after a reboot) and don't want to be bothered with typing the passphrases to add the keys to ssh-agent right away because I'm lazy and I know I won't be using SSH during that session.

If I press Ctrl-C, keychain and the whole rest of the .profile is skipped.

Is there a built-in way to skip keychain without skipping the rest of .profile?

My shell is Bash, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert this line in your .profile before your `eval ...` line.

```
trap "echo -e '\nkeychain skipped'" SIGINT
```

You can still skip your `eval ...` with Ctrl+C. `trap` catch your Ctrl+C, show some text and then continue in your .profile.